# Elasticsearch Define mapping template for a certain type of index

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, dynamic-mapping, elasticsearch-8

I wanted to know if there is a way in elasticsearch 8.x to define a mapping template such that whenever an index of say the certain name comes in a mapping is applied to it on the fly.

I have a ES cluster where all my indexes follow the pattern as `earnings-*`, for example, `earnings-2022-11`, `earnings-2022-12` etc. The mapping i want to apply is for a nested object. Currently, i apply the mapping as follows (manually):

```
PUT earnings-2022-11/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "my_salary": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
  }
}
```

I looked into the [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) side of things, but I see that these need to be done when I am creating an index, in my case, I am doing a bulk_index creation so I don't think this would work, or I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html):

```
PUT _index_template/earnings_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["earnings*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "my_salary": {
          "type": "nested"
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": {
    }
  },
  "priority": 100,
  "composed_of": [],
}
```